# Distinguishing user-supplied translation strings

Tags: i18n-l10n

I'm working on a site which was developed in English, now it is being translated into German.

The customer has been entering some of the German strings using the translation interface admin/config/regional/translate/translate and I am able to export them from admin/config/regional/translate/export.

My question: is there a way for me to see, either in the .po files or somewhere else *where* the translation came from? I want to focus in on the translations which have been done by hand by my customer so I don't do them again.